# Postgres: how to use subquery correctly?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, postgis

I have the following query

```
CREATE TABLE test_buffslip AS
SELECT
   ST_INTERSECTS(
     (SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.005) FROM segments where class = 7) 
     ,geom)
FROM segments;
```

Resulting in:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I want to use the buffer created on the subquery to select features from the main table.

Probably there are better ways to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown the data, table defs, explained the problem, etc, I can't really show a specific query. The general idea is to use the subquery in `FROM` with an alias, like:

```
CREATE TABLE test_buffslip AS
SELECT
   ST_INTERSECTS(...)
FROM (
  SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0.005) 
  FROM segments where class = 7
) seg_buffers;
```